# Difference between superuser and root

Tags: unix, ubuntu, terminal, root, sudo

I am using some online tutorials to learn the terminal in Unix systems.

Apparently `root` has full permissions everywhere, but it is inconvenient to `su` to `root`, do what you need to do, and then `exit` back to your normal username.

`sudo` apparently circumvents this, but I have some questions.

When you use `sudo`, it doesn't ask you for `root`'s password, it asks for *your* password.

So what stops you from just `sudo`'ing everything and mimicking the same functionality of having logged directly into `root` using the `root` password?

Comment: When you say "terminal", you probably mean "shell".

Comment: What's the difference between terminal / shell / console? I thought they were all synonymous

Comment: Oh, and when you're done with `su`, you don't `su` back to your normal username. You type `exit` or press control-D to exit the subshell.

Comment: You're right (and that was in my tutorial, too, I should have known better), fixed the OP

Comment: A terminal is hardware, or emulated hardware, that displays characters and takes keyboard input. A console is more or less the same thing. The program that runs in a console and lets you interact with the OS is a shell. Probably `bash`, if you're using Linux.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you use `sudo`, it doesn't ask you for root's password, it asks
>   for your password.

You must have recently authenticated. This could easily change this so that it authenticates you everytime:

```
sudo visudo
# that will open /etc/sudoers in vi/vim

# type the following to search the file:
/Defaults
# hit n to go to next result

# Find line that says:
Defaults        env_reset
# and change it to:
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=0
# 0 is time in minutes
```

You could also use `nano /etc/sudoers` if you are more comfortable with `nano` I would recommend looking into vim though.  The difference between nano and vim is like the difference between microsoft notepad and sublime/caret.

```
# Vim cheat sheet for this tutorial
i    # insert mode
ESC  # exit insert mode (and other modes)
:wq  # write changes (w) quit (q)

# a little more advanced:
:%s/search/replace/gc
# replace all instances of search and ask for confirmation:
```

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

> So what stops you from just `sudo`'ing everything and mimicking the same
>   functionality of having logged directly into root using the root
>   password?

Great question! You are apparently part of the sudoers group. Most distros (Distributions of linux\unix) have this group as wheel. Check out `usermod` to change this for users.

You can confirm the group name in `/etc/sudoers` :

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL

## Same thing without a password
# %wheel        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
# ^^^ ENSURE THAT THIS IS COMMENTED OUT (or not present) ^^^
```

**Not giving a user sudo access would prevent this.**

This is also a great thing:

Everybody and their brother has a `root` account on their system a lot of script kiddies try to brute force `root` accounts as well as other common usernames like `postgres`. It is in your best interest to lock down the root account mitigating ssh brut force attacks. This can be done with `passwd -l` (**RAN AS ROOT**).

By having a sudo user you can still do admin tasks like installing software and creating new users.

> Apparently `root` has full permissions everywhere, but it is
>   inconvenient to `su` to `root`, do what you need to do, and then `su` back
>   to your normal username.

If you are going to do extended tasks as root I would recommend:

```
sudo -i
# do whatever you need to do
^D 
# CTRL+D This will terminate your current shell and take you back 
# to your previous shell whereas su root and su username will take 
# you two shells away from your initial session.  This probably won't 
# effect you besides MAYBE session history (I am not sure about that).
```

As always be careful because you can really mess up your system as a super user.

### As for your title question:

> Difference between superuser and root

Ubuntu99 does a great job of summing this up:

https://askubuntu.com/a/592838/212470

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `sudo` is to allow certain users to run certain programs in certain ways, all of which can be controlled by the `/etc/sudoers` file and/or files in `/etc/sudoers.d`. And it logs those uses. So, a system operator, for example, can take backups, or a more senior admin can kill runaway processes, but neither of them gets the complete, unlimited access that `su` would give them.

Comment: Logs uses in what way? Every command inputted into the console gets logged?

Comment: Not everything, but `sudo` commands are normally logged.

Answer (score 0):

The **root** user is a build in user with administrative privillages in this application. **root** is the super user for the system, meaning that it has unlimited access to the files.

The root user has following additional role:

To create multiple administrator of an application and message them.

root user can restrict and manage admin users access and their privillages.